# Django autocomplete select does not work when deployed

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I deployed an app in Pythonanywhere, and the Django autocomplete light for the admin page isn't being loaded, However when I run the app in the local host it works.

For it to load, I need to set where the static files for the DAL are

```
/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dal/static/autocomplete_light

/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light
```

I'm using django 1.10, python 3.4

Comment: You don't need to “set where the static files for the DAL are”. You need to run `./manage.py collectstatic` in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by doing the following

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/myuser/myapp/static'
```

Static Files

URL              Directory

```
/static/    /home/myuser/myapp/static
```